# Extra symbols appear between characters when printing to console

Tags: c++

I have this code snippet, with the purpose of getting the list of paths in the system PATH variable and printing them on the CMD console;

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string path = getenv("PATH");

    string tempo = "";
    list<string> pathList;

    for(size_t n = 0; n < path.size(); n++)
    {
        char delimiter = ';';

        if(path.at(n) == delimiter)
        {
            if(!tempo.empty())
            {
                pathList.push_back(tempo);
            }
            tempo.clear();
        }
        else{
            char aChar = path.at(n);
            tempo.append(&aChar);
        }
    }

    list<string>::iterator listIter;

    for(listIter = pathList.begin(); listIter != pathList.end(); listIter++)
    {
        cout << *listIter << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Every time I compile and run on the CMD console I get output lines similar to this;

```
C►■":►■"\►■"P►■"y►■"t►■"h►■"o►■"n►■"2►■"6►■"\►■"S►■"c►■"r►■"i►■"p►■"t►■"s►■"
```

Is it memory corruption or not? And what exactly am I missing?
Am on Windows 7 64bit, compiling using MinGW (g++ 4.8)]

Comment: It's *waaaaay* too pretty to be "corruption"!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a closer look at the following two statements:

```
char aChar = path.at(n);
tempo.append(&aChar);
```

Apparently, you are trying to append a `char` to a `std::string`. However, you are actually append a NUL terminated string to `tempo`.

Replace the code with:

```
char aChar = path.at(n);
tempo += aChar;
```

or:

```
char aChar = path.at(n);
tempo.push_back(aChar);
```

Comment: Just a nitpick. The string (or rather, the char*) which he attempts to append is not null-terminated.